# Calculate probability that my chances are 50/50, despite limited but favorable data

Tags: probability, finance

Let's say you're trading forex, and you set a random trade, setting the stoploss and take profit exactly the same. Theoretically, in an infinite number of tries, your chances of success are 50/50 (ignore spread).

Now, you have a strategy whereby, after 500 tries, you've managed a 67% success rate. Assuming market conditions remain the same, how can you calculate the chances that your 67% success rate will return to 50/50 after 1000 tries? 10,000?

Comment: First, I think you may be on verge of making the "gamblers fallacy", if you flip a coin 100 times and have 67 heads, and then try to use that data to infer future prospects on flips of the FAIR coin, because it has no effect on the next outcomes. It is still 50/50. You just experienced an in probable event which does happen from time to time maybe. That said I do not completely understand forex stop order and other one?

Comment: Also maybe you would have to use your one data point of 67% to try and infer the variance of the probability distribution. Not sure if that is a manifestation of the above fallacy.

Comment: Whether or not I'm dealing with the gamblers fallacy is exactly what I'm trying to figure out. What are the chances that I've just created a quarter that lands on heads 67% percent of the time?

Comment: I'll look up variance if the probability distribution when I get home, thanks. Maybe I can also calculate the probability that a fair coin lands on heads 335/500 times in a random 500 flip sequence.

Comment: sorry my probability and statistics knowledge is poor these days, but I think you should be able to solve the problem simply by the binomial probability distribution. Variance won't be an issue and the question is valid and not a case of gamblers fallacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a required amount of failures and thus success to get back to $50$ percent overall.

$$\frac{335+x}{1000}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Solve for $x$

$$335+x=500$$

$$x=500-335=165$$

So you need exactly $165$ success in the next 500. This here isn't gamblers fallacy and is perfectly valid to ask what is the probability of getting $165$ success out of $500$ trials.

To figure this, use the binomial distribution.

$$P=\binom{500}{165}(0.5^{165})(0.5^{335})$$

$$=\binom{500}{165}(0.5^{500})$$

Wolframalpha tells me that is about $5.95 \times 10^{-15}$ or very unlikely.

Comment: Also we can see if it was really 50/50, than your 67 percent is pretty unlikely event.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (and what I was hoping to see), thank you. For anyone reading this now: a better metric for measuring this particular question is a binomial distribution range. While an exact result of 335/500 is all but impossible, it won't give you a true insight into how well you did. You should be looking for the chances that it falls between say, 60% and 74%. In my case, it seems there's less than a 0.04% chance that this happened by random coin-flipping chance. It only allows up to 300 possibilities, but here's a cool tool: https://goo.gl/OZ0oAu.

Comment: This also won't be exact, because you have to set your own acceptable range, but I think it gives me a pretty good idea of what I'm dealing with.